# Сбрасывает сохранения localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

Столкнулся с такой проблемой с localStorage.

В локальное хранилище идет запись Кликов, после перезагрузки запись остается. Но на сайте текущее количество кликов 0. После когда делаешь клик значение в локальном хранилище сбрасывается до 0

Вот код

```
<div class="balance__container">
   <div id="clicks-count" class="balance">0.000</div>
</div>
<div id="big-btn" class="poiner">
   <div draggable="false" class="pointer__img"></div>
</div>
```

```
var clicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0); // Всего кликов
var clickPower = 0.001; // Начально значение клика

const onClick = () => {
    document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = (clicks + clickPower).toFixed(3);
    clicks = clicks + clickPower;
    updateStorage(clicks);

    console.info(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
}

function updateStorage(clicks) {
    parseInt(localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks.toFixed(3)));
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попрошу автора прочитать про разницу между `parseInt` и `parseFloat`.
`parseInt` - возвращает целое число округлённую вниз, то есть 0.98 округляет к 0

```js
let clicks = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0); // Всего кликов
let clickPower = 0.001; // Начально значение клика

insertText(clicks);
const onClick = () => {
  clicks = clicks + clickPower;
  insertText(clicks);
  updateStorage(clicks);

  console.info(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
}

function updateStorage(clicks = 0) {
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks.toFixed(3));
}

function insertText(clicks) {
  document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks.toFixed(3);
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<div class="balance__container">
  <div id="clicks-count" class="balance">0.000</div>
</div>
<div id="big-btn" class="poiner">
  <div draggable="false" class="pointer__img">Click</div>
</div>
```